# Ninject: Construct generic class from non-generic

Tags: c#, generics, ninject

I have the following hierarchy in Ninject:

```
public interface IReader {}
public interface IReaderAsync {}

public class Reader: IReader{}
public class ReaderAsync : IReaderAsync{}

public interface IDatabaseReader : IReader, IReaderAsync {}

public class DatabaseReader : IDatabaseReader
{
    public DatabaseReader(IReader reader, IReaderAsync readerAsync){...}
}
```

These classes are bound, constructed and loaded as expected in Ninject using these bindings:

```
Bind(typeof(IReader)).To(typeof(Reader));
Bind(typeof(IReaderAsync)).To(typeof(ReaderAsync));
Bind(typeof(IDatabaseReader)).To(typeof(DatabaseReader));
```

Additionally I have a separate class which is constructed (soley) from an `IDatabaseReader`:

```
public class DatabaseReader<T> : IDatabaseReader<T> 
{
    public DatabaseReader(IDatabaseReader databaseReader){...}
}
```

The binding I am using is:

```
// open binding
Bind(typeof(IDatabaseReader<>)).To(typeof(DatabaseReader<>));
...
Kernel.TryGet<IDatabaseReader<TestEntry>>();
```

But the kernel returns null..
What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: `public interface IDatabaseReader : IDatabaseReader`, that can't be right. Please reread your question thoroughly. There are multiple mistakes in there, which make it hard for us to interpret your question.

Comment: Sorry about that; it is resolved now.

Comment: I have never worked with Ninject, so I have no idea what you're trying to do. But would binding a closed type work? Like: `Bind(typeof(IDatabaseReader<TestEntry>)).To(typeof(DatabaseReader<TestEntry>))` ?

Comment: No that doesn't work either... still null.

Answer (score 0):

After rebuilding a separate, simpler impl of the problem and proving to myself that it would load, I came to realize I wasn't loading the Ninject bindings that I thought I was at runtime. So problem solved: user problem.